# Production optimization - what type of problem?

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, discrete-optimization

I want to make an algorithm that distributes orders $O_1,O_2,\dots$ to equipment $E^1,E^2,\dots$ so they can be processed in an optimal way.

Different orders require different equipment for the processing steps, but which equipment may be used for which step is already known in the form of a tuple e.g. $(E^3,E^8,E^9)$.

For every piece of equipment there may be more than one instance: $E^k_l, l \in \{1,\dots,p \} $

The time $t \in \mathbb{R}^+_0$ spent on each equipment is determined by the amount of material to process (as specified by the order) and the speed of the equipment (as a property of the equipment).

Each equipment may process exactly one order at any given time.

The processing steps have to happen in the order specified in the tuple

It is possible to have more than one choice of equipment for a certain processing step, I will write this as $(\{E^3,E^4\},E^8,E^9)$. So it may be quicker to process on a certain machine if that one is available.

The optimization goal would be to process as many orders as possible during the available time $T \in \mathbb{R}^+_0$.

It should be possible to assign higher weights to certain orders so they get preferential treatment.

I may include more constraints later, but at this point I would like to keep it "simple".

I have a background in mathematics and some practical experience in programming and simple optimization.

At this point my problem is to find a start in tackling the problem since I don't really know what type of problem this is, and to check if I'm formalizing this meaningfully. Please excuse (and correct) my notation, I've been away from university for quite a while...

I am looking for a numerical solution and a decent approximation should suffice - it competes with solving the problem with excel and possibly some pieces of paper.

Comment: The goal of processing as many orders as possible during the available time is likely to have some unexpected or unwanted consequences.  Basically the tasks that can be completed rapidly will get priority over tasks that take more time, until only slower tasks remain in the "book" of orders.  But as a simple algorithm, try computing how quickly each order can be done, then optimizing the scheduling of the quickest tasks on the available equipment.

Comment: I guess I could calculate that - but what type of algorithm would I use to do the schedulung? Is this reducible to a standard problem?
I thought about using time slots and treating it as an assignment problem... but that might not be such a good idea...

Answer (score 1):

This is called parallel machine scheduling or also the job-shop problem. Small instances can be solved to optimality by formulating the problem as Mixed Integer Programming problem. For larger problems we can use a MIP model and just stop before optimality. That will give often very good solutions (a MIP solver will even give some information about how the gap could be between the best found solution and the best possible solution). For larger problems many heuristic approaches have been developed, including interesting meta-heuristics (such as genetic algorithms). These methods provide good solutions but no feedback about the quality (how good).

Typical pictures of solutions are:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, I will check out how that works.
should and I mark this as complete now and start a new question if i hit a roadblock or leave this open and add details to the question?

Comment: @BootstrapBill  Either approach is fine. In my experience the details matter a lot. Often these models start out simple but can get complex quickly once you start working on them in a practical setting.

Comment: do you happen to know if there is a suitable r package available? so i can get started and test stuff?
i will leave this open for now

Comment: There are MIP solvers available for use with r. [Here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/genetic-algorithms-a-simple-r-example/) is an example of a genetic algorithm with R.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently writing my master thesis on this problem. I used Julia/JuMP to develop the model. If you are a student, you could also get free solver licenses of Gurobi and CPLEX, which can be used with Julia/JuMP. These are much faster than GLPK or Cbc and really help during development.

What you are describing are really 2 distinct types of problems. Firstly, a job shop model. Here, every job has a routing assigned to it, which contains all operations that must be performed in order to complete a job. The routing can be different for every job. However, in the generic models, the machines are statically assigned to the operations. Hence, if alternative resources exist (multiple instances of the same machine) an operation could be processed on any of those. Thus, you might want to use a heuristic in a first step to generate an assignment and then pass it to your scheduling model. Here, I would try to assign all processes that can be assigned to a set of resources, so that all potential resources are as equally utilized as possible.

You could also combine resource assignment and scheduling in one model, but this gets computationally demanding very fast. Also you could assign resources to operations manually or use a second MIP.

Regarding the available time in which all jobs must be completed, I would not consider this in the beginning. If you restrict your objective value too much, the model will be infeasible. Depending on the size of the model this can be very frustrating to fix. Develop a simple working example and then extend it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular situation there will be queuing of task (orders) for the equipment resources.  Each order has a deterministic requirement for a certain amount of time on a particular type of equipment, so from the point of view of an order, there is no mystery about where the order needs to go "next"; it must be sent to a queue for that type of equipment.

The Question anticipates that there may be multiple instances of an equipment type, so these queues can have multiple "servers".  That is, the types of equipment will in general be "single queue/multiple servers".

Note that an order requires, at any point in time, only one resource to progress (a server of the type of equipment next in its processing plan).  Therefore it is impossible for [resource deadlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) to occur.

A type of greedy algorithm for scheduling is the following.  Eliminate all orders which cannot be fulfilled, even with open resource availability, within time $T$.  The problem is to complete as many of the remaining orders as possible within that time constraint.

The queues should be dynamically reorganized when a step of one order is completed, and the order leaves its current server to go into the queue for its next processing step.  Since it is desired to complete as many orders as possible, the queue should prioritize those orders whose time-to-fulfillment is least (adding up all the time required for all unfinished processing steps), using as a tie-breaker the least time required by the equipment type of the current queue.

After a feasible schedule for $N$ orders to be completed is found, it is possible to review the results of "greedy" scheduling for improvement opportunities.  In particular there may be task whose critical path involved a lot of time on otherwise underutilized equipment, and by randomly prioritizing these task ahead of some that required less overall time but on "bottleneck" types of equipment, it is sometimes possible to obtain additional throughput.